# Adding to an object field

Tags: java, object

The goal is to create a two player dice throwing game with text menus through console. I have 3 classes, Game, Player and Dice. The player class just has string player name field and int player score field The dice class has the RNG code but most of the game is in the game class.

When starting a game I name two players (text taken from user) and create two player objects. I can call the "roll dice" method which returns the score from one round of the game, but how do I add that score to the field already defined in the player objects?

There is supposed to be one object per player but I don't seem to be able to refer to each individual object. Is there a problem with having those objects created in a different method but of the same class as the method thats trying to increment the player score?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Game
    {
        // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
        private int x;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Game
         */
        public Game()

        {
            // initialise instance variables
            x = 0;

        }

        public void menu()
        {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


           System.out.println("Welcome to My Dice-and-Roll Game!");
            System.out.println("=================================");
            System.out.println("(1) Start a New Game");
            System.out.println("(2) Play One Round");
            System.out.println("(3) Who is leading now?");
            System.out.println("(4) Display Game Help");       
            System.out.println("(5) Exit Game");        
            System.out.println("(6) Choose an option:");       

        int selection = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                // Perform "original number" case.
                        nameplayers();
                        playround();
                break;
            case 2:
                // Perform "encrypt number" case.
                        System.out.println("(2) ");
                break;
            case 3:
                // Perform "decrypt number" case.
                                    System.out.println("(3) ");
                break;
            case 4:
                // Perform "quit" case.
                                    System.out.println("(4) ");
                break;
            default:
                // The user input an unexpected choice.



        }


    }

    public void nameplayers()
    {
    String namep1;
    String namep2;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the name of player 1: ");
    namep1 = scanner.next( );
    Player P1 = new Player();
    P1.setName(namep1);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of player 2: ");
    namep2 = scanner.next( );
    Player P2 = new Player();
    P2.setName(namep2);


    }

        public void rolldice()
        {
            int dice1;
            int dice2;
            int rollTotal;

            // put your code here
          dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
          dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
          if(dice1 == dice2){
              rollTotal = ((dice1 + dice2) *2);
            }
             else {
                 rollTotal = (dice1 + dice2);
                }



          System.out.println(" has rolled a " + dice1 + " and " + dice2 + " which totals " + rollTotal + " points");
          P1.addScore(rollTotal);

    }

    public void playround()
    {
    String namep1;
    String namep2;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("The dice are thrown!");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    }
    System.out.println("..");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    }
    System.out.println(" ..");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    }
    System.out.println("   :");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    }
    System.out.println("    ..");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    }


    rolldice();

    }
    }

        import java.util.Scanner;


public class Player
{
    // the name of the player
    private String playerName;

     // the current score of the player
    private int playerScore;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Player
     */
    public Player()
    {

    String playerName = "";

    int playerScore = 0;

    }


    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        // put your code here
        playerName = newName;
                    System.out.println("Player name set as " +
                               newName);

    }
    public void addScore(int addScore)
    {
        // put your code here
        playerScore = playerScore + addScore;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the `Players' outside of the method. Because you declare`Player player`inside the`namePlayers()` method, as soon as you leave the method (method scope) the objects are no longer visible / referenced, and become available to be garbage Collected.

Define the Players as local variables to your `Game` class:

```
public class Game
{
    Player player1;
    Player player2;
}
```

Then in your `namePlayers()` method, just create and set the players:

```
P1 = new Player();
P1.setName(namep1);
System.out.print("Enter the name of player 2: ");
namep2 = scanner.next( );
P2 = new Player();
P2.setName(namep2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most object oriented way to do it would be to write a method that updates the private variable. Something like:

```
public void updateScore(int score) {
    this.x = x + score;
{
```

You would call this method on your player object like:
    player1.updateScore(resultPlayer1);
    player2.updateScore(resultPlayer2);